# pagedlist in partial view not working correctly- MVC4

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, pagedlist

I have implemented paging in my partialview.

Here is my paging-

```
  <div class="pagination-right">
                @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("_AllVendors",
new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter, @Class = "pagination" }))
```

Now I wanted to load results according to pages within this partial view i've made.

So I used this script to not to navigate to partialview page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.pagination-right a').click(function () {
            var page = $(this).text();
            if (this.href == "") { return; }
            else {
                $.ajax({
                    url: this.href + '&page=' + page,
                    type: 'GET',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('#allvendors-partial').html(result);
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am loading result in a div with id- `allvendors-partial`.

**Problem-**

I am getting problem when any of page is clicked again, then it doesn't load it into div `allvendors-partial` instead it goes to its partialview.

How Do I get this working correctly?

Answer (score 1):

### First item - e.preventdefault():

As you have multiple return points in your code, e.preventDefault() will stop the anchor's default click behaviour (for even the blank `href` you check for, which would cause a page reload).

It is your call as to whether you want a page reload on clicking a blank href, but if not simply add e.preventdefault() like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.pagination-right a').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
```

If you decide to use this, you will not need the `return false`.

### Second item - Use event delegation:

You are also reloading your paging anchors each time, via the partial page, so you also need to use the delegate version of `on` to handle the click:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(document).on('click', '.pagination-right a', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var page = $(this).text();
            if (this.href == "") { return; }
            else {
                $.ajax({
                    url: this.href + '&page=' + page,
                    type: 'GET',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('#allvendors-partial').html(result);
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;   // Not needed if you use e.preventdefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

This works by catching `click` at a higher unchanging level of the DOM (i.e. document), *then* apply the jQuery selector/filter and figure out what was clicked.

Basically if you use Ajax to replace controls on the page, then you are also replacing/deleting any event handlers that were attached to them (e.g. with `.click(...)`).